# LNK 2001 Error in Visual Studio 6

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've been thrown a bit in the deep-end with a C++ app I need to get running and I cant get it to build.

It appears that just about error source file throws out this error:

BindActivView.obj : error LNK2001 : unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall CNOLEError::AddError(struct IUnknown *,struct _GUID const &:" (?AddError@CNOLEError@@QAEXPAUIUnknown@@ABU_GUID@@@Z)

Could someone please point me in the right direction with how I go about fixing this?

Comment: Visual Studio 6 is more than antiquated. Upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You omit some obj/lib file in your project.

You probably use some lib files which need to be linked together with your output.

Comment: I don't suppose there is some easy way to find out what the missing lib is?

Comment: I don't think so.Referenced method is CNOLEError::AddError(IUnknown *,&GUID const), which is not a standard method of MS built in objects.Developer should know what libraries are refereed by code.